# Can you tell me what deploy.prototxt in Caffe model is for?

Tags: python, model, caffe

Can you tell me what deploy.prototxt in Caffe model is for?

Comment: Edge detection in spatial or in frequency domain?

I want to ask why everywhere is used to do edge detection in spatial domain and not in frequency domain with FFT of image and apply HP filter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A neuronal network has two phases: traning phase and test phase. In trainng phase we find the weights by mean of a training algorithm. In test phase we use the trained net for a specific task.  In caffe library, generally, each phase has its own architecture. Thus, for example, the [caffe net  convolutional network](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet) in training phase is composed of:

**data layer**: this layer read training data from hard disk.

**convolutional network**: conv layers, relu layers, max-pooling layers, and inner product layers.

**loss layer**: Softmax with loss. It is necessary to calculate the error between labels and output of fc8 layer (see picture below) and then backpropagate the gradient.

While in test phase it is only composed of:

**input layer**: this layer read data of memory. It is a mutable pointer in C++.

**convolutional network**: conv layers, relu layers, max-pooling layers, inner product layers, and sofmax layer (named prob below).

Note that in test phase loss layer is not necesary.

Below it is shown training architecture (left) and test (deploy) architecture (right) obtained using [Netscope](https://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/editor).

[image]

Comment: Edge detection in spatial or in frequency domain?

I want to ask why everywhere is used to do edge detection in spatial domain and not in frequency domain with FFT of image and apply HP filter. Thank you.

Comment: Mišika Biľanská It is due to generally the spatial size of kernels of convolutional layers are of 3x3, so in this case is more efficient compute the convolution than the FFT. FFT is more efficient in applications in which the kernel is larger. Please check the computacional complexity comparative: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/ReviewFourier/FFT_Convolution_vs_Direct.html